# Can't Get Index of Songs to Show in Songs package (Linux)

Tags: songs

I'm on Manjaro Linux and I'm trying to write a songbook using the songs package. Everything works, but I can't generate the song index and author index. Also, is it possible to generate the index so that each entry has a hyperlink to the actual song in the generated pdf file?  Here is a sample of my tex file. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.1in}
\settowidth{\versenumwidth}{1.\ }
\pagestyle{empty}


\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}
\newauthorindex{authidx}{cbauth}



\begin{document}



\showindex{Complete Index of Songs}{titleidx}
\showindex{Index of Authors and Composers}{authidx}



\songsection{Songs}

\begin{songs}{titleidx,authidx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Songs Start %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\beginsong{Olvidarte}[by={Ricardo Arjona},
cr={Notes: Capo on the 4th fret}]
\hspace{-5mm}
\gtab{C}{032010:021034}
\gtab{G}{320003:210034}
\gtab{Am}{X02210:002310} 
\gtab{F}{133211:134211} 
\gtab{Em}{022000:021034}
\gtab{G*}{355433:021034}
\gtab{Em}{022100:021034}


\beginverse
Olvi\[C]darte es mas di\[G]ficil que encon\[Am]trarse al sol de \[Em]noche
que enten\[F]der a los po\[C]liticos o com\[G]prar la torre ei\[Am]ffel
mas di\[F]ficil que fu\[C]marse un habano en a\[G]merican air\[Am]lines
mas di\[F]ficil que una flor \[C]plastica mar\[G]chita
\endverse

\beginverse
olvi\[C]darte es mas di\[G]ficil que una \[Am]flaca en un bo\[Em]tero
que encon\[F]trarse a un gato \[C]verde, o a un cu\[G]bano sin sa\[Am]bor
mas di\[F]ficil que lady \[C]di en \[G]la estacion del \[Am]metro
olvi\[F]darte es tan di\[C]ficil olvi\[G]darte
\endverse

\beginchorus
Olvi\[C]darte, \[G]olvi\[Am]darte \[F]
es querer jalarle el \[Em]pelo a una bo\[Am]tella \[F]
es creer que la me\[Em]moria es un cassette para bo\[Am]rrar
olvi\[F]darte es recor\[C]dar que es impo\[G]sible
olvi\[C]darte, \[G]olvi\[Am]darte \[F]
incluso es mas di\[Em]ficil que aguan\[Am]tarte \[F]
si extraño tu neu\[Em]rosis y tus celos sin ra\[Am]zon
como \[F]no extrañar tu \[C]cuerpo en mi col\[G]cho-u- \[C]on.
\endchorus

\beginverse
Olvi\[C]darte es un in\[G]tento que no \[Am]lo deseo \[Em]tanto
por que es \[F]tanto que lo in\[C]tento que me a\[G]cuerdo mucho \[Am]mas
y he lle\[F]gado a sospe\[C]char que mi a\[G]fan de no acor\[Am]darme
es lo \[F]que me tiene en\[C]fermo de re\[G]cuerdos
olvi\[C]darte es lo que es\[G]pero para \[Am]reanudar mi \[Em]vida
harto \[F]de seguir soñan\[C]do con la \[G]posibili\[Am]dad
de que un \[F]dia por e\[C]rror, o pu\[G]ra curiosi\[Am]dad
le pre\[F]guntes a un a\[C]migo por mis \[G]huesos
\endverse


\beginchorus
Olvi\[C]darte, \[G]olvi\[Am]darte \[F]
es querer jalarle el \[Em]pelo a una bo\[Am]tella \[F]
es creer que la me\[Em]moria es un cassette para bo\[Am]rrar
olvi\[F]darte es recor\[C]dar que es impo\[G]sible
olvi\[F]darte, \[G]olvi\[Am]darte \[F]
incluso es mas di\[Em]ficil que aguan\[Am]tarte \[F]
si extraño tu neu\[Em]rosis y tus celos sin ra\[Am]zon
como \[F]no extrañar tu \[C]cuerpo en mi col\[G]cho-u- \[C]on.
\endchorus



\beginchorus
\[F]  es querer jalarle el \[Em]pelo a una bo\[Am]tella \[F]
es creer que la me\[Em]moria es un cassette para bo\[Am]rrar
olvi\[F]darte es recor\[C]dar que es impo\[G]sible
olvi\[F]darte, \[G]olvi\[Am]darte \[F]
incluso es mas di\[Em]ficil que aguan\[Am]tarte \[F]
si extraño tu neu\[Em]rosis y tus celos sin ra\[Am]zon
como \[F]no extrañar tu \[C]cuerpo en mi col\[G]cho-u- \[C]on.
\endchorus


\endsong
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Songs End %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to answer your question, please tell us which commands you are executing to compile your document.  Also, knowing which version of the Songs package you're using would be helpful.

Comment: I'm using Kile  as an editor and PDFLaTex to compile my document. I'm not sure what version of the songs package I'm using. As far I can tell, the songs package that I'm using is part of the texlive-music package (version 2018.49818-1) that I installed from the Manjaro repositories.

Comment: You can find out which version of the songs package you are running by reading the .log file generated by pdflatex.  Look for a line that says, "Package: songs YYYY/MM/DD vNNN Songs package" where NNN is a version number.  The answer to your question depends on which version of the package you're using.  If you have the most recent version (3.1), the answer is documented here: http://songs.sourceforge.net/songsdoc/songs.html#sec10.3

Answer (score 2):

Generating indexes requires executing extra commands after you've compiled your document with pdflatex, and then running pdflatex again to incorporate the generated indexes.  If you're using version 3.x, the commands for your document are:

```
pdflatex mybook.tex
texlua songidx.lua cbtitle.sxd cbtitle.sbx
texlua songidx.lua cbauth.sxd cbauth.sbx
pdflatex mybook.tex
```

The general build procedure for books with indexes is found in [section 10.3 of the package documentation](http://songs.sourceforge.net/songsdoc/songs.html#sec10.3).  The package also includes automated build scripts for this in the form of GNU makefiles for Linux and batch scripts for Windows, in case you don't want to type these commands manually every time.

Since you are already loading the hyperref package, the generated indexes will hyperlink the song numbers in the indexes to the songs they reference.